# How do i create MySQL tables with php using HTML forms?

Tags: php, mysql

I am interested in creating MySQL tables in PHP using HTML forms.An ideal example would be;
1. A html form is presented where i enter table name and names of the fields that the table will have for example id,firstname,lastname and email.
2.On submitting the form, the table should be added to the back end database with its respective fields. I have the following code.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "book";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$tablename = $_POST['MyGuests'];
$id = $_POST['id'];
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];


// sql to create table
$sql = "CREATE TABLE My (

id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
MyGuests VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(50)
)";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Table MyGuests created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error creating table: " . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>


  <form name="form1" method="post" action="mark.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <table width="80%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3">
   <tr>
    <td>ID</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="id" id="id"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Table name</td>
     <td><input type="text" name="MyGuests" id="MyGuests"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>First name</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Last name</td>
   <td><input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>Email</td>
   <td><input type="text" name="email" id="email"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
   <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Save Table">
   </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

The problem i have is whenever i run the script, a MySQL table is created automatically.Attempting to create the table using the form doesn't seem to work.What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: place your code in another file and pass it in `action` field of form.

Comment: Where is mark.php

Comment: Is something not working?  I would expect issuing a `CREATE TABLE` SQL command would work just like any other.  That is, there's nothing really *preventing* you from using whatever SQL code you want when issuing a query from PHP.  What's the problem?

Comment: `CREATE TABLE` will only work once, you need `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST`

Comment: are you sure you really want to do that?

Comment: what error did you get back, seeing you're checking on the mysql side? plus on the php side; what are they?

Comment: it seems you either logged off or are ignoring comments; I have now left this post, seems like a waste of time/typing.

Comment: I think he has not given the form redirection correctly.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the table from creating itself automatically, I think you would need to isolate your create statement inside an if statement :

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

// Create table here

    $sql = "CREATE TABLE My (

    id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    MyGuests VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(50)
    )";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "Table MyGuests created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error creating table: " . $conn->error;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $servername = "localhost";
 $username = "root";
 $password = "";
 $dbname = "book";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ( $conn->connect_error ) 
{
   die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$tablename  = $_POST[ 'MyGuests' ];
$id         = $_POST[ 'id'       ];
$firstname  = $_POST[ 'firstname'];
$lastname   = $_POST[ 'lastname' ];
$email      = $_POST[ 'email'    ];


// sql to create table
$sql = "CREATE TABLE {$tablename} ( $id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, $firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,$lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,$email VARCHAR(50) )";
if ( $conn->query($sql) === TRUE ) {
    echo "Table $tablename created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error creating table: " . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
```

?>
Please please send the values into fields:
Please check the fields value:http://nimb.ws/I7Y1Qy

Comment: You need to create a file "mark.php" in same folder and save the php code into this file. your form action is going to 'mark.php' file.